# Trouble dereferencing double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'd like to implement a stack using a linked list.

In order to implement pop() for my stack, I have the caller pass a double pointer (pointer to a pointer) that (eventually) points to the top of my stack ( first entry in linked list ).

The reason why I'm doing it this way is because this way the caller can keep a static pointer to the stack.

My linked list element struct :

```
struct Element {
int value;
struct Element *next;
};
```

pop() implementation:

```
int pop (struct Element **stack) {
    int popped_value = *stack->value;
    *stack = *stack->next;
    return popped_value;
}
```

The issue I have is trying to dereference the double pointer **stack. This code generates the following error:

```
error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure
error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure
```

In my mind, either *stack->value or **stack.value should work to retrieve popped_value, but I get the identical error.

Comment: Just use good ol' `stack-->next`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`->` has higher precedence than the dereference operator, so that's like trying to dereference `stack->value` since the `->` gets done first, and `*` done second. You need to use parentheses:

```
int popped_value = (*stack)->value;
*stack = (*stack)->next;
```

Or, as wallyk suggested in the comments, dereference the argument to get a single pointer and use that:

```
struct Element *sip = *stack;
int popped_value = sip->value;
*stack = sip->next;
```

Comment: Either use parens, or explicitly use an intermediate value, `struct Element *sip = *stack;` and `*stack = sip->next;`

Answer (score 8):

`->` has higher [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) than dereferencing (`*`) in this line:

```
*stack->next
```

You are saying:

```
*(stack->next)
```

Which fails since `stack->next` doesn't make sense.

You want:

```
(*stack)->next
```

instead.